# Как запустить Unit test

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, mstest

Как запустить Unit Test с командной строки?

Comment: @rdorn ответ? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть стандартное средство - MSTest.exe.

> MSTest.exe — это запускаемая из командной строки программа, которая служит для запуска тестов. У этой программы есть несколько параметров, с помощью которых можно настроить ее работу.

Подробнее в документации ([тык](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms182489.aspx)), переписывать всё сюда не вижу практического смысла. Если что-то конкретно непонятно/не получается - уточняйте вопрос, или задайте новый.